# Pointer to Array of Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of int pointers `int* arr[MAX];` and I want to store its address in another variable. How do I define a pointer to an array of pointers? i.e.:

```
int* arr[MAX];
int (what here?) val = &arr;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Should just be:

```
int* array[SIZE];
int** val = array;
```

There's no need to use an address-of operator on `array` since arrays decay into implicit pointers on the right-hand side of the assignment operator.

Comment: @moteustch Well, you got a pointer to the array's data, which is _almost_ the same.

Comment: Yes, `val` is a pointer to the array of `int` pointers (semantically speaking) ... if you dereferenced `val`, you'll end up with your array of pointers again, i.e., you can do `(*val)[INDEX]` .  So since `val` is holding the address to the start of an array of `int*`, then it's a pointer to an array of pointers.

Comment: @Ivella: Could you please explain?  The OP asked how to define a pointer to an array of pointers, and this answer shows one way that can be done that is considered legal C-code.

Comment: @Jason `val` is not a pointer to an array of pointers. `val` is a pointer to the first pointer in the array. `(*val)[INDEX]` in not equivalent to `array[INDEX]`. Instead, `val[INDEX]` is equivalent to `array[INDEX]`. Derefrencing `val` just gives you the first pointer in the array. You haven't explained how to make a pointer to an array of pointers, but you have explained how to make a pointer the first pointer in an array.

Comment: Hey @Jason, do you have a reference for _"since arrays decay into implicit pointers on the right-hand side of the assignment operator"_?

Comment: @RafaelEyng You can check out [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1462103/649233)

Answer (score 31):

The correct answer is:

```
int* arr[MAX];
int* (*pArr)[MAX] = &arr;
```

Or just:

```
        int* arr  [MAX];
typedef int* arr_t[MAX];

arr_t* pArr = &arr;
```

The last part reads as "pArr is a pointer to array of MAX elements of type pointer to int".

**In C the size of array is stored in the type, not in the value. If you want this pointer to correctly handle pointer arithmetic on the arrays** (in case you'd want to make a 2-D array out of those and use this pointer to iterate over it), **you - often unfortunately - need to have the array size embedded in the pointer type.**

Luckily, since C99 and VLAs (maybe even earlier than C99?) MAX can be specified in run-time, not compile time.

Comment: `int* (*pArr)[MAX] = &arr;` is read - "(the variable) pArry is a pointer to an array of pointers to integers", correct? I'm trying to go by this: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, arrays are implicitly convertible to pointers, so it would be:

```
int ** val = arr;
```

Comment: I believe that's going to throw and error in the complier for mis-matched type since `arr` is actually of type "array-of-pointers-to-int` rather than "pointer-to-int"

Comment: Arrays ARE convertible to pointers... But not the other way round. And also Pointers-to-arrays are not implicitly convertible to pointers-to-pointers. Et cetera, et cetera.

Comment: But if an array is convertible to a pointer wouldn't the original arr the same as `int** arr`? So `&arr` would be `int ***`, no?

Comment: @moteutsch: No, because `array` is considered in the C-type system to be of type "array-of-int-pointers".  Written out in C, that would be of type `int* ()[]`.  Now if you took the `&array`, you'd end up with the C-type `int* (*)[]` which says that `array` is a pointer to an array of `int*`.  This is *NOT* the same as `int**` or any other pointer-to-pointer type.  For instance, if you added a value of 1 to a type of `int* (*)[]`, you'd increment that pointer by the whole value of the array, where-as if you incremented a `int**` by 1, you'd only increment the size of a `int` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

According to this source http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html, by using the "go right when you can, go left when you must" rule, we get the following 2 meanings of the declarations given in the previous answers -

```
int **val ==> val is a pointer to pointer to int
int* (*pArr)[MAX] ==> pArr is a pointer to an array of MAX length pointers to int.
```

I hope the above meanings make sense and if they don't, it would probably be a good idea to peruse the above mentioned source.

Now it should be clear that the second declaration is the one which moteutsch is looking for as it declares a pointer to an array of pointers.

So why does the first one also work? Remember that

```
int* arr[MAX]
```

is an array of integer **pointers**. So, val is a pointer to, the pointer to the first int declared inside the int pointer array.

Comment: This link http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html was excellent!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SIZE 10
int *(*yy)[SIZE];//yy is a pointer to an array of SIZE number of int pointers
and so initialize yy to array as below -

int *y[SIZE];   //y is array of SIZE number of int pointers
yy = y;         // Initialize
//or yy = &y;   //Initialize
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26218458)

Comment: @double-beep: There's at least _some_ explanation here—it's just not as obvious as it's handled as inline comments in the code block. I agree that providing a quick introduction would be useful here, though, and especially given that this is an old question with quite a few existing answers.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer is simply:

```
int **val;
val = arr;
```

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know there is no specific type "array of integers" in `c`, thus it's impossible to have a specific pointer to it. The only thing you can do is to use a pointer to the int: `int*`, but you should take into account a size of int and your array length.

Comment: `int []` is an array of integers and it is *different* from `int *`, but will implicitly decay to `int *` when used as a function argument or in a context where pointer arithmetic is done.

Comment: C certainly has array types and they are not equal to pointer types, if that's what you're thinking. Try compiling `int main() { int a[1] = {0}; int i; a = &i; return 0; }`

Comment: Most important difference between array types and pointer types is how they respond to `sizeof`.