# Array of pointers and pointer to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I don't quite understand where the error is here:

```
int *parr[22];  // Array of int* pointers
parr[0] = ptr1;
parr[1] = ptr2;
//... 

int *(*pparr)[22]; // A pointer to a int* array[22]
pparr = parr; // ERROR
```

the error tells me `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int *[22]' to 'int *(*)[22]'`

how come that the types are not equal? The name of the array should be equal to a reference to the first element of the array, something like

```
parr => &parr[0]
```

so the line seems right to me

Comment: You want http://stackoverflow.com/a/6130884/315052

Comment: Must be `pparr = &parr;` for the types to be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `pparr` is `A pointer to a int* array[22]` so you need to write

```
pparr = &parr;
```

You need to store address in the pointer and not the pointer itself.

It is same like when you have

```
int a=3;
int *b;
b=&a;
```

You are storing address of a in b, similarly you need to store address of `parr` in `pparr`

EDIT: To clarify OP's comment

You can't assign the address of the first element, but the address of the pointer that is pointing to first element.(therefore `pparr = &parr;`)

Comment: Yes but the name of the array should be equal to a reference to the first element of the array, so I should already have the address

Comment: ya thats why we are not writing `pparr = &parr[0]` we are writing `pparr=&parr`

Answer (score 1):

An `int*[22]` can decay to an `int**`, but you cannot assign an `int**` to an `int*(*)[22]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *(*pparr)[22];  //This one is an array of function-pointers returning an int pointer. 

int **pptr;  //Points to an array of pointer
```

So you can write

```
pptr = parr;
```